# Angular 2 Promise design

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm struggling to find a good design pattern to resolve initial values with promises as used in Angular 2 - I'm quite used to the deferred pattern as used in Angular 1.

I'm using Promises to resolve a collection once-off on initialisation. Later on I'd like to calculate some values from the collection and return it.

```
export class HierarchyService {

    someCollection;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        myService.getCollection().then(value => this.someCollection = value);
    }

    public calculateValuesFromCollection(example: number) {
        //only return once someCollection has been resolved during initialisation!
        let someVariable = /* calculate some values from someCollection */
        return someVariable;
    }

}
```

How do I use promises in Angular 2 to achieve this?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is or what problem you try to solve, but promise is not an Angular pattern https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm trying to initialise a variable asynchronously and then at a later stadium make use of the resolved value. Angular 2 uses the pattern as you specified - I just tried to specify I'm not using the deferred pattern as with $q in Angular 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
getSomePromise().then(val => this.someVar = val);
```

This doesn't guarantee though that `this.someVar` will have a value when you read from it. Only after the response arrived it will hava a value.

Alternatively you can use

```
 this.someVar = getSomePromise();
```

If you want to access the value, you use

```
 this.someVar.then(val => console.log(val));
```

or

```
<div>{{someVar | async}}</div>
```

Comment: Gunter, would that be an anti-pattern to use a `collectionReady` variable that would go true once the nginit promise resolves, and register an observable on it later, so when `calculateValuesFromCollection` is called it would wait for the flag to become true before doing the algorithm over the collection?

Comment: I'd consider it an antipattern. `Promise` already provides exactly that with the `then()` method where you can pass a callback that gets executed when the value becomes available.

Comment: Since the promise invokes the possibly long-running action on the then, I feel like this solution looses a bit of performance. Otherwise you cold "preload" and then just wait for the finishing time, not for the full load. That said, it's technically the best solution.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller I don't understand what you think is the difference between "cold preload" and "full load". The `then()` call only executes the async call once. For subsequent calls when the result is already available it calls the callback almost immediately. Only when there are a **lot** of subsequent calls you'll be able to measure a difference.

Answer (score -1):

You Need to use 'Map' and 'Subscribe' instead of promise. For Example

```
this.service.get(response)
            .subscribe(
            res =>this.object=res,
            error => this.errorMessage = error,
        );
```

Comment: As I understand, an observable works great for subscribing to a stream of events (as with RxJS). I have a variable that will be resolved only once, so I hoped to use the promise pattern.

Comment: But promise is not an angular2 pattern

Comment: This does not address the problem at all

Comment: `Observable` is also not an Angular2 pattern. Angular uses it and tries to support it as good as possible, but `Promise` is well supported throughout Angular2 as well.

Comment: You can convert Observable to Promise and use as you desire.